# SQL Group by month and join

Tags: sql, date

I have 3 different queries and need to find a way to display results in a single gridview, but this way is creating 3 different grids.
My code is this and try to find a way to join in a sinlge one with rows showing months and columns showing "Laptop", "Pc" and "Total".

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0) AS MyMonth, COUNT(stb_group) AS Laptop 
FROM inventary 
WHERE (activation_date > '10-01-2013') AND (stb_group = 'Laptop') 
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0)


SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0) AS MyMonth, COUNT(stb_group) AS PC 
FROM inventary 
WHERE (activation_date > '10-01-2013') AND (stb_group = 'PC') 
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0)


SELECT     DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0) AS MyMonth, COUNT(stb_group) AS Units
FROM         inventary
WHERE     (activation_date > '10-01-2013')
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0) AS MyMonth, 
COUNT(case when stb_group = 'Laptop' then stb_group end) AS Laptop,
COUNT(case when stb_group = 'PC' then stb_group end) AS PC, 
COUNT(stb_group) AS Units
FROM inventary 
WHERE (activation_date > '10-01-2013')  
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, activation_date), 0)
```